# Dynamic Find and Replace Procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using with success a Find and Replace Procedure that passes in 3 values Range (colRange), SearchString, ReplaceString and its been working fine. Issue is now I have more requirements. Those are now:

- Find and Replace in the same column (existing working fine)
- Find and Replace in the same column, then update another column
- Find and Replace in the same column, then update another two columns

So what I ended up doing in the short term was changing the procedure from `findandreplace (ColRange, SearchString, ReplaceString)` to
`findandreplace (FirstColRange, FirstSearchString, FirstReplaceString, SecondColRange, etc, etc)`

I would then call this by going `findandreplace "A1:A", "test", test1, "C1:C", "blah1", "blah2", "", ""`

in the sub routine I added in some code that went if NOT SecondColRange "" then go do another search.

Obviously this is FAIL.

However, I can't seem to work out the best way to do this using best practices.

So I went back to the drawing board and implemented a Dictionary Object with a delimiter and using split. Got it working again just passing in 3 strings. Can anyone please help me out making this dynamic based on requirements above?

Here is the code I'm using. I know it needs a clean-up but I'm just trying to it up and running functionality-wise first.

```
Sub Cleanup2()

    Set awb = ActiveWorkbook

    With awb.Sheets("Sheet1")


        Dim arrColOrder As Variant
        Dim Counter As Integer, ndx As Integer
        Dim dict As Object
        Dim ItemKey As Variant

        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        Counter = 0

        arrColOrder = Array("ColRange|A1:A", "SearchString|test", "ReplaceString|test1")


        For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

            v = Split(arrColOrder(ndx), "|")

            dict.Add v(Counter), v(Counter + 1)

        Next ndx



    End With


    WSFindAndReplaceAndUpdate "Sheet1", dict


    Set dict = Nothing

End Sub


Sub WSFindAndReplaceAndUpdate(wSheet As String, dictionary As dictionary)

    Set awb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim DsRangeCol As Range
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ItemKey

    Set oSht = awb.Sheets(wSheet)
    LastRow = oSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set DsRangeCol = oSht.Range(dictionary.Item("ColRange") & LastRow).Find(dictionary.Item("SearchString"), LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not DsRangeCol Is Nothing Then
        strFirstAddress = DsRangeCol.Address
        Do
            Set DsRangeCol = awb.Sheets(wSheet).Range(dictionary.Item("ColRange") & LastRow).FindNext(DsRangeCol)
            DsRangeCol.Value = Replace(DsRangeCol.Value, dictionary.Item("SearchString"), dictionary.Item("ReplaceString"))
            oSht.Range(DsRangeCol.Address) = DsRangeCol.Value

        Loop Until DsRangeCol.Address = strFirstAddress
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the replacement in the second and third coulmn in the same row or are these total different replacement jobs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd suggest you read the [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve] help center pages, to get a better idea of what kind of questions are best answered on this site, and what kind of questions end up doing poorly. As it stands there's not really a *specific programming issue* here, which makes your question a notch *too broad*; if you can [edit] your post to narrow it down to a specific problem, you'll be more likely to get what you're looking for.

Comment: OK thanks I will remember that for next time. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Optional` Keyword before any Parameter:

```
Function asdf(a As Integer, Optional b As String)
```

Now the first parameter is necessary and the second one is optional.

You can also set a default value for optional parameters that will be used if no parameter is passed:

```
Function asdf(a As Integer, Optional b As String = "test")
```

Then you are able to check if the parameter was modified by using a simple if

```
If b <> "test" Then
```

Calling the function without passing a parameter for b:

```
asdf 12
```

Comment: Cant believe I have never come across Optional. I had a read and that's exactly what I need to implement. I also read that if its a variant you can use IsMissing which I will use as well. Thanks again